# Why was the "Middle Sidebar Advertising" page removed? Please undelete it

Tags: discussion

Why was the "Middle Sidebar Advertising" page removed? Please undelete it.

I don't see any valid reason to delete it, but if there is one please enlighten me.

https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7081/middle-sidebar-advertising

The archive.org version is here: https://web.archive.org/web/20230602052007/https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7081/middle-sidebar-advertising

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe it or not, it was deleted by SE, not us. They have a clean-up script which deletes poorly received posts with no recent activity, and that's what acted here:

[image]

> This post is hidden. It was automatically [deleted](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/help/auto-deleted-questions) last month by [Community](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) (Bot).